# Joining two Excel Files and Displaying in a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have two different Excel files (.xls). There is a column named `KATIP` in `excel1.xls`, and there is a column named `SAVCI` in `excel2.xls`. I want to get these columns and merge them into a table named `Nobet` with 2 columns: `SAVCI` and `KATIP`.

Then I want to show them in a Gridview Control in ASP.NET. I have working code, but when I run it, it's getting the first column named `KATIP` then getting the column named `SAVCI`. They are not merged, and they appear as different columns.

```
OleDbConnection DBConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" +
    Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/excel1.xls") + ";" + "Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes\"");

DBConnection.Open();
string SQLString = "SELECT * FROM [Page1$]";
OleDbCommand DBCommand = new OleDbCommand(SQLString, DBConnection);
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(DBCommand);
DataSet ds = new DataSet("Nobet");
da.Fill(ds,"Nobet");
DBConnection.Close();
DBConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" +Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/excel2.xls") + ";" + "Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes\"");

DBConnection.Open();
DBCommand = new OleDbCommand(SQLString, DBConnection);
da = new OleDbDataAdapter(DBCommand);
da.Fill(ds,"Nobet");
GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Nobet"];
GridView1.DataBind();
DBConnection.Close();
```

Comment: No answer for this easy question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem... here is what I did:

```
OleDbConnection DBConnection = new
    OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" +
    Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/savcilik_katip.xls") + ";" + "Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes\"");
DBConnection.Open();
OleDbCommand DBCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sayfa1$]", DBConnection);
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(DBCommand);
DataSet ds = new DataSet("Nobet");
da.Fill(ds, "Nobet");
DBConnection.Close();
DBConnection = new
    OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" +
    Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/savcilik_savci.xls") + ";" + "Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes\"");
DBConnection.Open();
DBCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sayfa1$]", DBConnection);
da = new OleDbDataAdapter(DBCommand);
da.Fill(ds, "Nobetci");

DBConnection.Close();
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables["Nobet"].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    ds.Tables["Nobet"].Rows[i]["SAVCI"] = ds.Tables["Nobetci"].Rows[i]["SAVCI"];
}

GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Nobet"];
GridView1.DataBind();
```